# Why am I getting an error and an infinite loop?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the question.
 Write a shell (text-based) program, called fruit_list.py, that creates the list of fruit names ('Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Water Melon', 'Pear') and asks the user to pick a number from 1 to 5. The program then prints the corresponding item on the list. Note the difference between the item number and the list index. See the example below.
Example:

```
PS C:\Users\ssiva\Desktop> python fruit_list.py
Pick a number between 1 and 5: 3
You got a Banana.
PS C:\Users\ssiva\Desktop>
```

This is my updated input:

```
x = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Water Melon', 'Pear']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fruits = str(raw_input())

while fruits > "5" or fruits <= "0":
print " Pick a number between 1 and 5:"
fruits = str(raw_input()) 

else:
 print x
```

AND THE ERROR IS THAT IT IS PRINTING ALL OF THE FRUITS. I WANT EACH NUMBER TO COORELATE WITH EACH FRUIT BUT ALL OF THEM ARE PRINTING.

This is the error: 
mes-MacBook-Air:desktop me$ python fruit_list.py

Pick a number between 1 and 5:
0
 Pick a number between 1 and 5:

Pick a number between 1 and 5:
7
 Pick a number between 1 and 5:
2
['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Water Melon', 'Pear']
mes-MacBook-Air:desktop me$

Comment: Did you mean `y = int(raw_input())`?

Comment: It would rase TypeError, since you are comparing `str` with `int`

Comment: for loops in python involve iterating over an iterable (such as a list, tuple, array, generator, etc).  `for y in x:` is a syntax error, since y is already defined.  try: `for fruit in x: print(fruit)`.

Comment: Better yet, go in to your teacher's office hours.  There's a lot going on here that you'd do well to learn to sort out.

Comment: the error was invalid syntax in line 8

Comment: I didn't get any error with the code you posted. Infinite loop, yes. But no syntax error.

Comment: Don't use `x` and `y` - these are very confusing names - use, for instance, `fruits_list` and `numbers_list` instead.  `for fruit in fruit_list: print fruit` makes a lot more sense, right?  Also. per `while list_integers > 5` - it's clear that this does not make sense - a list can't be said to be "greater than" a number - only numbers can be greater than numbers.

Comment: Here is a update of what i wrote ! Im trying to get each number to corresspond with the fruits but im just getting all of them printed at the same time . What am i doing wrong?   x = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Water Melon', 'Pear']
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
fruits = str(raw_input())

while fruits > "5" or fruits < "0":
 print " Pick a number between 1 and 5:"
 fruits = str(raw_input())
else:
 print x

Answer (score 0):

The prompt you posted doesn't imply there's a need for looping.

```
fruit_list = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Water Melon', 'Pear']
usr_num = int(input('Pick a number between 1 and 5.'))
print fruit_list[usr_num-1]
```

That works for me. I'm not sure where you were headed with the loop. Please avoid using x and y for items that can be explicitly named ('fruit_list').

Edit: Just wanted to add that I am subtracting 1 from usr_num because python indexing starts at 0 and not 1.

Comment: yea i see that but im trying to do a while loop so whenever a user inputs a number greater than 5 it'll automatically tell them to enter a number between 1 and 5. And if it is between those ranges than it'll print the fruit corresponsing to it. im running 2.7 and my professor said there is a while loop involved im just stuck on how to proplerly do without messing up

Comment: I still don't see why a while loop would be useful. What you are describing can be done using an if statement.